# Why is JSON parsed ok in Postman, but not when using Python3 requests module?

Tags: json, python-3.7

I get the following JSON response (snippet) from an API call with a status code 200 when using Postman.

When I make the same request in Python3 using requests module and json.loads(), it throws an error on the line with "77" (expected). What I don't understand is how is Postman able to parse the json and display it "pretty" when all other json validators fail?

```
"Row": {
    "Cell": {
        "name": "InstanceID",
        "77"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "Guid",
        "3ce599a911a24938be584e206c21f9c6"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "TriggerTime",
        "2019-10-09T23:01:41.1300000Z"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "TriggerEntity",
        "16430d626563484f885ce30622b5c6b7"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "TriggerEvent",
        "4"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "CreationTime",
        "2019-10-09T23:01:41.0670000Z"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "AckTime"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "AckBy",
        "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "AckReason",
        "28673"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "ExternalInstanceID",
        "-1"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "OfflinePeriod",
        "0"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "TriggerEventSubType",
        "0"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "State",
        "1"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "InvestigatedBy",
        "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "InvestigatedTime"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "HasSourceCondition",
        "False"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "DynamicContent"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "Priority",
        "1"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "Latitude"
    },
    "Cell": {
        "name": "Longitude"
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not even vaguely close to being valid JSON.  It's missing an outer set of curly braces, has duplicate "Cell" keys (each of which would overwrite the previous one), and has a mixture of dict-like and list-like elements in many of the Cells which is simply meaningless.

Comment: well... yea.. i kinda implied that by stating it was a "snippet"... Postman doesn't complain however. Hence the question.